# Calling a Fibonacci function

Tags: python, function, fibonacci

When I call this function from the client by writing `FIBONACCI`, it won't show the result:

```
def FIBONACCI(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return FIBONACCI(n-1) + FIBONACCI(n-2)
```

Comment: what is your question??

Comment: _"it won't show the result"_ Well, did you call `print` on the result?

Comment: did you _call_ the function like _at all_

Comment: We can't help you without a [mcve].

Comment: @Aran-Fey  def requests (keyword):
    elif (keyword == "FIBONACCI"):
        conn,addr=serverSocket.accept()
        nr=conn.recv(2048)
        number=nr.decode('UTF-8')
        return FIBONACCI(nr);
When I call it from the client side by writing FIBONACCI it doesnt show the result

Comment: @Nita Please _read_ the link I posted...

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you wrote a working function, but didn't call it, and print the result. This code should do the job:

```
def FIBONACCI(n):  
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return FIBONACCI(n-1) + FIBONACCI(n-2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(FIBONACCI(10))
```

Comment: @Nita you should submit a new question as this point with all your code, don't just add in a comment.